# get value of input after button click

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am trying to get a value of an input after a button click. I found some things on the internet but I still haven't succeeded. I know it has something to do with setState. But I dont know how I can apply this in my code. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as following:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    value: ''
  }
}
onChangeText = (value) => {
  this.setState({ value });
}

onPress = () => {
  alert(this.state.value);
};

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
        value={this.state.value}
      />
      <Button
        onPress={this.onPress}
        title="Click"
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: When I use your code I get the following error: "Can't find variable: value"

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:
    (here you dont need button to save the input in state,it automatically saves the data in state)

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: "",
    }   

<TextInput onChangeText={(text)=>{this.setState({data: text})}} />
```